# pseudocode for loop to java for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, insertion-sort

how do I translate the following pseudocode to java code:

```
for k:=0 to (j - i - 1)
{

    a[j-k] :=a[j-k-1]

}
```

This is part of the insertion sort code from a discrete math book, I'm confused if I should put `k++` or `k--` or something else as part of the java for loop after the `to` statement

Comment: I posted an answer. However, if your only concern was whether or not k++ or k-- was the issue, it would really just be a matter of trying both and seeing which one works.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is the sort of beginner-level fundamental question that you should be able to figure out from any Java tutorial.  Everybody on here is a volunteer, and you are expected to do basic research and NOT ask questions that can be easily answered 1000 other places on the Internet.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].  SO is not a tutorial site.

Comment: A simple Google search would have supplied the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudocode:

```
FOR k := 0 to (j - i - 1)
   a[j - k] := a[j - k - 1]
END FOR
```

would convert to the Java code:

```
for (int k = 0; k <= (j - i - 1); k++){
   a[j - k] = a[j - k - 1];
}
```

(the <= might need to be a <, depending on whether or not "to" implies inclusivity in this case)

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the insertion sort, is to keep comparing the current element with it's previous, if it was smaller; swap. Insertion sort has worst time complexity with O(n^2) in case the array was sorted in a descending order, and has O(n) for best time complexity.

The following code describes the insertion sort.

```
      int key,temp,i,j; 
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
             key = arr[i];
             j = l - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && key < arr[j]) {
                 temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
                j--;
            }
        }
```

You have to set i =1 and j to it's previous, compare, if arr[i] < arr[j] then swap.